# R plot function gives out weird answer

Tags: r, plot

I tried to use R plot to get the curve for some functions. Sometimes, I got very weird results. Here is an example

```
u=c(2,2,2,2,2)
elas=function(P){
  prob=P/sum(u,P)
  return(prob)
}
plot(elas,0,6)
```

This code gives out the plot like this: 
[image]

It is obviously not right. The right code should be like this:
[image]

I know that if I change the 3rd line of the code to be

```
  prob=P/(sum(u)+P)
```

It would work. But I do not understand why my original code does not work. Does it mean that I cannot plot a function which embeds another function?

Answer (score 1):

`sum(u,P)` is a single value equal to the sum of all the values in `u` and `P`. So in `elas`, every value of `P` get's divided by the same number (313 in your example).

`sum(u) + P` is a vector containing each individual value of `P` with `sum(u)` added to it. So in the second version of `elas` (which I've called `elas2` below), `P/(sum(u) + P)` results in element-by-element division of `P` by `sum(u) + P`.

Consider the examples below.

```
u=c(2,2,2,2,2)
x=seq(0,6,length=101)

sum(u,x)
```

> ```
> [1] 313
> ```

```
sum(u) + x
```

> ```
>   [1] 10.00 10.06 10.12 10.18 10.24 10.30 10.36 10.42 10.48 10.54 10.60 10.66 10.72 10.78
>  [15] 10.84 10.90 10.96 11.02 11.08 11.14 11.20 11.26 11.32 11.38 11.44 11.50 11.56 11.62
>  [29] 11.68 11.74 11.80 11.86 11.92 11.98 12.04 12.10 12.16 12.22 12.28 12.34 12.40 12.46
>  [43] 12.52 12.58 12.64 12.70 12.76 12.82 12.88 12.94 13.00 13.06 13.12 13.18 13.24 13.30
>  [57] 13.36 13.42 13.48 13.54 13.60 13.66 13.72 13.78 13.84 13.90 13.96 14.02 14.08 14.14
>  [71] 14.20 14.26 14.32 14.38 14.44 14.50 14.56 14.62 14.68 14.74 14.80 14.86 14.92 14.98
>  [85] 15.04 15.10 15.16 15.22 15.28 15.34 15.40 15.46 15.52 15.58 15.64 15.70 15.76 15.82
>  [99] 15.88 15.94 16.00
> ```

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))

elas=function(P) {
   P/sum(u,P)
}

dat = data.frame(x, y=elas(x), y_calc=x/sum(u,x))

plot(dat$x, dat$y, type="l", lwd=2, ylim=c(0,0.020))
plot(elas, 0, 6, lwd=2, ylim=c(0,0.020))
curve(elas, 0, 6, lwd=2, ylim=c(0,0.020))
```

[image]

```
dat$y - dat$y_calc
```

> ```
> [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> [43] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> [85] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> ```

```
elas2 = function(P) {
  P/(sum(u) + P)
}

dat$y2 = elas2(x)

plot(dat$x, dat$y2, type="l", lwd=2, ylim=c(0,0.4))
plot(elas2, 0, 6, lwd=2, ylim=c(0,0.4))
curve(elas2, 0, 6, lwd=2, ylim=c(0,0.4))
```

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, if I plot a function rather than a data frame, R will still simulate "x" first, then put all the value in the x vector in the function to calculate the value of the function and store it as y. Then form a data frame with x and y, then plot the data frame.

Comment: But if I have some function like sum(x), it will sum all the x's and use that value, rather than each single x to calculate the function value. However, if I really need to have some functions like sum in there, and hope to sum each individual x with u, before calculating y and plotting, what should I do? In this simple example, I can just write sum(u)+x, but when it comes to more complicated functions, I am not sure how to deal with it.

Comment: Yes. `plot` calls the `curve` function when you feed `plot` a function (like `elas`). You can see the code for `curve` by typing `curve` in the console. Look in the function code for this line: `x <- seq.int(from, to, length.out = n)`. That's where `curve` generates the x values that it's going to plot and also use to generate y values.

Comment: x is a vector. If you want to add 10 to each element of x you do `x + 10`. If you have two vectors that you want to add together element by element, you can do `x + u`. But note that in this case, if the vectors are not of equal length, the shorter one will be recycled. For example, run `1:7 + 1:3` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

sum(u+P) = sum of each value in u plus P

sum(u) + P = sum of values in u plus P.

Example: `u = c(1,2,3), P = 5`

```
sum(u+P) = (1+5) + (2+5) + (3+5) = 6+7+8 = 21
sum(u) + P = (1+2+3) + 5 = 6 + 5 = 11
```

For

```
elas <- function(P){
    prob=P/(sum(u+P)
    return(prob)
}
```

with `u <- c(2,2,2,2,2)`:

```
y <- elas(0:6)
print(y)
#output of print y:
0.00000000 0.03225806 0.06451613 0.09677419 0.12903226 0.16129032
0.19354839
plot(0:6,y)
```

[image]

For

```
elas <- function(P){
    prob=P/(sum(u) + P)
    return(prob)
}
y <- elas(0:6)
print(y)
#Output of print(y)
plot(0:6,y)
0.00000000 0.09090909 0.16666667 0.23076923 0.28571429 0.33333333 0.37500000
```

[image]